# How to interpret binary neural network results?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I have using a dataset from Kaggle focused on heart disease predictions with 8 inputs and binary outputs. I have tested the data using logistic regression, random forests, SVM, and a simple neural network. Surprisingly, the best model is random forests. However, I'm having trouble with the neural network. The result, from the data, is either a 1 or a 0, so binary. The neural network works, but the results are odd, at least to me.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

NN = Sequential()

NN = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(8,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid),
])

NN.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

NN.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=1)
test_loss, test_acc = NN.evaluate(X_test, y_test)

y_predd = NN.predict(X_test)
```

I expect my results to be a value between 0 and 1, so anything over 0.5 is 1 and anything less is 0. But my prediction of the test set gives me values from 0 to 9. Any idea what I did wrong? Could I be overfitting the data?

I tested the network on a known datapoint:

```
X_new = [[70,1,0,145,174,0,1,125]]
X_new = sc.fit_transform(X_new)
NN.predict(X_new)
```

and I get the following result, which is wrong: 0.99--it should be 0.

Comment: `0` to `.9` you mean?

Comment: No, the y_pred results are as follows: [[9.72895026e-01], [2.30669975e-05]. I would understand if it was 0.9 and 1, given the results are percentage confidences. I don't understand the result of 9.7 given the optput can only be between 0 and 1.

Comment: You are probably not familiar with scientific notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation  9.78e-1 = 0.978, so it's class 1.

Comment: Do you need any more explanation? If yes add that to question otherwise this has to be closed I guess.